# ViewPager problem

Tags: android, view

As give in this [document](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) . I did the same.While running i am using a emulator which has android 2.3.3(means API 10 ) support. It is showing no compatible device found.Any idea from any body plz share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [android compatibility package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) and you can set the min sdk to 4 (1.6).

I have created a demo app in a [post of my blog](http://android-argentina.blogspot.com/2011/09/playing-with-new-viewpager-class.html). Feel free to grab the code.

Comment: I already added this using android tools->add compatibility library.Still it is showing the same error.

Comment: @AndroidPower: Set the `android:minSdkVersion` to 4 in your `AndroidManifest`

Comment: Your blog helps me a lot.Thanks Buddy. :)